# Is there a way I can access my Rails Application of my Ubuntu VM from my Windows 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, windows-7, virtual-machine

I got a Rails application (running on Thin server) running on my Ubuntu VM, how can I be able to access it from my Windows 7 OS? I already have the VM bridge option enable.
I tried using the IP address from my Ubuntu VM directly to my windows 7 browser, but nothing happens, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

- You need a Bridged adapter for your Virtual Machine
- You need to know your VM's IP address (`ifconfig | grep inet` on Ubuntu)
- Your VM needs to be turned on AND running the server

Then in your Windows 7 (or other computer in your local network, your smartphone for instance) you can open a browser and go to your VM's IP address + port (usually 3000).

So, the address to put in your browser **might look like this**:

```
http://192.168.1.5:3000/
```